# Repel Form from Going off Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, position, positioning

Currently the program bounces when the cursor gets near it but it just leaves the screen
I am having trouble keeping it on the screen (letting it bounce off the edge of the monitor)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;

        if(this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
        {
            this.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - (Cursor.Position.Y / 3) + (Cursor.Position.X / 2), Cursor.Position.Y - (Cursor.Position.X / 3) + (Cursor.Position.Y / 2));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I want to achieve a image that runs away from the cursor, but also cannot leave the screen (bounces back)

Comment: We don't know whats inside your head, or what you have been building for the last hour, please add more information as this is more than a little vague

Comment: the code doesn't paste easy, but that's all of it @TheGeneral

Comment: also don't worry about the somewhat random calculations

Comment: Also whats the question, i mean what are you trying to achieve? just try to add a little more information

Comment: @TheGeneral well I want to achieve a image that runs away from the cursor, but also cannot leave the screen (bounces back) the form is the image